# Simple html dom parser table to array

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom, html-table

I'm trying to parse the arrivals table from here [[1]](http://flightplan.romatsa.ro/init/fpl/flightslr/LRCL) and put in into an array to be able to format it and put it into a table.

I did some research here and there, I've got some code from other questions, but I can't make the array and table look as I'd like.

Anyone can help me out?

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://flightplan.romatsa.ro/init/fpl/flightslr/LRCL/');
$table = $html->find('table', 3);
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
// initialize array to store the cell data from each row
$rowData = array();
foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
// push the cell's text to the array
$rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
}
echo "<table>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[0]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[1]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[2]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[3]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[4]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[5]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[6]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[7]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $rowData[8]. " ";
echo "</td>";
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: So these are almost two separate questions. The first, is to parse the data into an array format that you can work with and the second to output the array into a desirable format.  It might help to solve the first problem first.  In order to do that, it would be useful to see a `var_dump($rowData)` output along with what data structure you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey Mike,the dump looks like this (right now): http://pastebin.com/KD6zP4Ui

Comment: that looks like two var dumps next to each other. Which is from $rowData?  If it is the second array, then your display code is not working because you have a multi-dimensional array. and echoing an array is just going to give you emptiness.

Comment: The actual code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/KyvcnzZj . And the dump looks like this: http://pastebin.com/86BtwGc0 . The source of the table is this: http://goo.gl/RuKloV , I'm trying to get the arrivals from there. I'm really appreciating your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe try putting each row into an array and then each cell into another array. Hopefully, that will do what you want.

```php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://flightplan.romatsa.ro/init/fpl/flightslr/LRCL/');

$table = $html->find('table', 3);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $flight;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

*Note: this solution requires the `simple_html_dom.php` library. [Get it here!](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)*