# How to use preg_match_all in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am currently in the process of developing a site for a football club.
I pick a ranking that is on an official website (I have permission). The problem is that there is no RSS feed, then I have to tinker.
I create a php file with this code:

```
    <?php

$adresse = "http://lafa.fff.fr/competitions/php/club/club_classement_deta.php?sa_no=2011&cp_no=272284&ph_no=1&gp_no=1&cl_no=3232&eq_no=1";
$page = file_get_contents ($adresse);

preg_match_all ('#<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" class="tablo bordure ac">(.*?)</table>#', $page, $prix);
// On stocke dans le tableau $prix les éléments trouvés

echo '<table>';

for($i = 0; $i < count($prix[1]); $i++) // On parcourt le tableau $prix[1]
{

    echo $prix[1][$i]; // On affiche le prix

}

echo '</table>';


?>
```

The problem is that I have that to integrate drupal and it does not works. I tried to create a module and create a function, same result.
I create a content page with php code, same result, it does not work.

How can I do that ?

Cheers

Update : In my drupal module.module:

```
    <?php

    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    function classements_liste(){   

        $url="http://lafa.fff.fr/competitions/php/club/club_classement_deta.php?sa_no=2011&cp_no=272284&ph_no=1&gp_no=1&cl_no=3232&eq_no=1";
        $dom = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));

        $tables = $dom->find('table');
        echo $tables[0];
        echo $tables[1];



    }

    function classements_menu() {

        $items['classements/list'] = array(
        'title' => 'Liste des classements',
        'page callback' => 'classements_liste',
        'page arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access callback' => true,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        );

        return $items;


    }


?>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concatenation as i define below :

```
$adresse = "http://lafa.fff.fr/competitions/php/club/club_classement_deta.php?sa_no=2011&cp_no=272284&ph_no=1&gp_no=1&cl_no=3232&eq_no=1";
        $page = file_get_contents ($adresse);
        preg_match_all('#<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" class="tablo bordure ac">(.*?)</table>#', $page, $prix);
        $data   =   '<table>'; // here the table is define
        for($i = 0; $i < count($prix[1]); $i++){
            $data   .='<tr><td>'.$prix[1][$i].'</td></tr>'; // add table row
        }
        $data   .=   '</table>'; // finish table
      $block['content'] = $data; // assign to block or simple print in case of page
```

Comment: How can a link a css file for this specific module ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to traverse the html structure rather than preg_match_all.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://lafa.fff.fr/competitions/php/club/club_classement_deta.php?sa_no=2011&cp_no=272284&ph_no=1&gp_no=1&cl_no=3232&eq_no=1');

$table = $html->find('table[class=\'tablo bordure ac\']', 0);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $row = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        $row[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $row;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522784/php-simple-html-dom-parser-table-to-array).

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Does it display an error?

Comment: The code works, but not in a drupal page, in a blank page like a basic php file

Comment: Yeah, but when you place it in drupal what happens?

Comment: The code works, but i want to display it in a drupal page, not like that

Comment: Mhm, I see, I am not too sure then, sorry :[

Comment: K, i keep working on that, if you have a solution, you know where I am ^^